# Get xml node properties via c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, properties

How to get node properties?So, i use Linq To Xml to parse file.
I try to do like that:

```
// load doc and then give elements.
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(pathToFile);
var elem = doc.Root
              .Elements("mode")
              .Where(o => o.Attribute("name") != null)
              .Elements("file")
              .Where(k => k.Attribute("name") !=null && k.Attribute("name").Value == filenameTag)
              .Elements("model")
              .Where(o => o.Attribute("name") != null)
              .Elements("class")
              .Where(c => c.Attribute("name") != null);


foreach (var el in elem)
{
    Console.WriteLine("First Attribute "+el.FirstAttribute.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Name "+el.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Last Attribute " + el.LastAttribute.ToString());

    var nodes=el.Nodes();
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("node "+node.ToString());
    }

}
```

Xml file:

```
  <modes>
    <mode name="mode1">
      <file name="file1.xml">
        <model name="Config" AllClasses="false">
          <ignore.class class="class5"/>
          <class name="class1" allProprs="true"/>
          <class name="class2" allProps="false">
              <property name="pr1"/>
              <ignore.property property="pr2"/>
           </class>
         </model>
       </file> 
    </mode>
</modes>
```

So, i get only string like this:

```
node <property name="pr1" />
node <ignore.property property="pr2" />
```

But how to get value "pr1" and "pr2"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you simply writing ToString representation of inner elements of class. That gives you whole content of properties elements. But you should get **value** of first attribute from each property element:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
string filenameTag = "file1.xml";
var classes = xdoc.Descendants("file")
                  .Where(f => (string)f.Attribute("name") == filenameTag)
                  .Elements("model")
                  .Where(m => (string)m.Attribute("name") != null)
                  .Elements("class")
                  .Where(c => (string)c.Attribute("name") != null);

foreach (var c in classes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + (string)c.Attribute("name"));
    foreach(var p in c.Elements())
       Console.WriteLine("Property: " + (string)p.Attributes().FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Outputs:

```
Name: class1
Name: class2
Property: pr1
Property: pr2
```

BTW it's much easier to write this query with XPath:

```
string xpath = String.Format("//file[@name='{0}']/model[@name]/class[@name]", filenameTag);
var classes = xdoc.XPathSelectElements(xpath);
```

Answer (score 2):

At the time when it is displaying:

```
node <property name="pr1" />
node <ignore.property property="pr2" />
```

You are iterating `<class>`. If you want to get the attributes of the child elements, then *ask for the attributes of the child elements*:

```
foreach (var attrib in el.Elements().Attributes())
{
    Console.WriteLine("node " + (string)attrib);
}
```

Which outputs: `pr1` and `pr2`, as requested

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XPath query and ask your XML-Document. The other option is to get the XmlNode and then extract the attributes from the node.

It's not LINQ, but it works.